# Where can I modify wordpress contact form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form

I downloaded a theme on the internet and am trying to modify its "contact" page. I cannot find the place to modify it anywhere on wordpress admin panel

[image: My contact page]

When I pressed on "edit page", there is no code of the contact form, I cannot edit the code

[image: Wordpress admin panel - Edit page]

I doubt the contact form is a plugin and look for it in my Plugin list. But no plugin for contact form either

[image: My list of plugins]

Where can I find the code/ settings so that I can customize this contact form?

Answer (score -1):

Download the wordpress theme, put it in a zip file, open it in WinRAR then click find and search for the string that will help you find out where the contact form is being generated. You can search for "Human Verification".